# Old house, one light flickering, changed fixture now intermittently flashing not a flicker , blink but totally random when starts and stops

Tags: wiring

This house is a little over 100 yrs old. wiring is newer than the house but has been replaced with newer wires. The old paper wrapped wiring is still there but cut off before the breaker box. The rewire was before Romex was common. Checked the voltage at the fixture and it's a steady 121.3 VAC absolutely no change in voltage even when blinking that's what throws me I can't see why incandescent would blink with steady voltage haven't yet checked current to see if there is anything abnormal there. The old fixture was pull chain for the switch. Still using that type switch on new fixture. But it will at random times start blinking for a random amount of time about two to five minutes and will go days without blinking then randomly starts again then shines steady. Tried incandescent and led bulbs and it still occurs, incandescent burns out after less than a day. LED last so for three days.

Comment: Are you saying that an LED lamp totally breaks after 3 days?

Comment: Would turn off the power and go over every connection on that circuit.  Loose connection probably causes odd currents.  Make sure every connection is tight and clean.

Comment: Since you seem to have steady power at the fixture but it's blinking/flickering, it seems that the issue might just be with the fixture itself. As a test, wire an outlet in place of the fixture and plug in a lamp to see if it flickers. If so, the problem is in the new fixture.